# Azure Machine Learning Recommendations API: Delete Build fails

Tags: azure, recommendation-engine

I'm using Azure's Recommendations API to generate product recommendations. I'm keeping Recommendations up to date via an SSIS package that updates the data, creates a new build for the data, and if the build succeeds, deletes any previously existing builds.

The API documentation is straightforward, and everything works fine except one call in particular fails for me returning a HTTP 406 error (Not acceptable - Accept header doesn't match a response type supported by the server).

Has anyone successfully deleted a build via this API Call?

According to [the documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-recommendation-api-documentation/#11-build) a Delete Build call should look like this:

Method=DELETE
{rootURI}/DeleteBuild?buildId=%27%27&apiVersion=%271.0%27

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

I just ran into this question... Did you resolve this issue?
In contrast with most of the functions, The datamarket version of the API requires a DELETE method to actually delete a build (as apposed to a GET) -- that may be the first thing to check.

Also, I want to make sure you are aware that the datamarket version of the API will be deprecated (please read the migration guide at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cognitive-services-migration-from-dm/ for more details).   You should now be using the Recommendations API Cognitive Service (see https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/recommendations-api ).

Either way, if you are still running into issue, feel free to contact us at mlapi@microsoft.com and we can check what may be wrong with your call.

Thanks!

Luis Cabrera

Recommendations API Program Manager